# Retrieve records from multiple tables some distinct, some not

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables in an existing mysql database of a directory type site.
Table mt_links contains basic info for each listing
Table mt_cl contains which listing above is in what category (I only want cat_id=1)
Table mt_cfvalues contains more details for each listing **It Can have repeated values**
Table mt_images contains image names for each listing.

I want all records from mt_links where the mt_cl cat_id=1, and for each of those records, I need all records in mt_cfvalues and cf_images matching the link_id.

I set up a select with Group_Concat and left joins, but ended up with repeating values in my results. I added Distinct, which cured the repeating values, but mt_cfvalues can have records with the same value, so now I'm missing a value I should have.

```
SELECT    a.link_id, 
          a.link_name,
          a.link_desc,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.value ORDER BY b.cf_ID) AS details,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.filename ORDER BY c.ordering) AS images
FROM      mt_links a
LEFT JOIN mt_cfvalues b ON a.link_id = b.link_ID
LEFT JOIN mt_images c ON b.link_id = c.link_ID
LEFT JOIN mt_cl d ON a.link_id = d.link_ID WHERE d.cat_ID = '1'
GROUP BY  a.link_id
```

I put together a SQLFiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f39e9/1

Is there an easier way? How do I fix the repeating / no repeating issue?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you encounter a repeated value?

Comment: Repeated values from mt_cfvalues should be included in my result. Notice in my fiddle, Link ID 1... In the Details column it should have returned "good,no cats,good"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of accomplishing what you seek.  Because the two subqueries return independent results, you can't combine the GROUP BY, which is why you were getting duplicates.

```
SELECT    a.link_id, 
          a.link_name,
          a.link_desc,
          cvf.details,
          imgs.images
FROM      mt_links a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT link_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY cf_ID) AS details
     FROM mt_cfvalues
     GROUP BY link_ID
  ) cvf ON cvf.link_ID = a.link_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT link_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(filename ORDER BY ordering) AS images
     FROM mt_images
     GROUP BY link_ID
  ) imgs ON imgs.link_ID = a.link_id
INNER JOIN mt_cl d ON a.link_id = d.link_ID 
WHERE d.cat_ID = '1'
```